# Get triggered build resource from Azure DevOps build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using 'batched CI' trigger for a number of pipelines in our Azure DevOps Server installation, as in

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - master
```

These pipelines in turn use build artifacts from another pipeline for performing their actions:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: artifacts
    source: Artifacts
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - master
```

After a triggered build has finished, I need to retrieve information on the exact build resource the triggered build was using, i.e. what artifacts it was based on. But I cannot find any information on that.

I've tried the [REST API for build items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), and that is supposed to contain properties `TriggerInfo` and `TriggeredByBuild`. But these never contain any information.

The information is clearly possible to retrieve, since every build summary in Azure DevOps contains the **Related/Consumed** artifact information. But does anyone here know how to retrieve this information?

Comment: In my case the `TriggerInfo` is with data. which ADO server you using?

Comment: I'm using Azure DevOps Server 2020.1. I can see that TriggerInfo contains information when a build actually has been triggered because of another. But in this case, the trigger is "Batched CI", but the build then uses the pipeline resource to fetch build outputs etc. And then TriggerInfo is empty.